# Receiving function name in C

Tags: c

I have a program like this,

```
void test(char* a)
{   
    printf("%s",a); // Trying to print the function name "add" here
    return;
}

int add(int,int)
{
  test(__FUNCTION__); // I need the function name add to be passed to the test function
  ...................
  ....................
}
```

But while building I am getting the error in a C compiler(gcc flavour) like this,

passing argument 1 of 'test' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Please have a look at this,

/R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html):

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function. This name is the unadorned name of the function.
>
> `__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`.

So, you're trying to pass a `const char *` to a `char *`, discarding the `const` qualifier. Since in your `test` function you aren't modifying the passed string, change its parameter type to `const char *`, promising to the caller that you aren't modifying its string.

By the way, to get `const` correctness right you should always remember to declare pointers as `const` if they are "input-only" parameters.

Comment: @Renjith G, your function receives constant pointer to char array, not array itself.

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature of `test` to

```
void test(const char* a)
```

GCC is complaining that you're converting a pointer to a constant string literal to a mutable pointer by calling `test`.